# Are there differences between string.replace / .strip / .find and the built-in functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-2to3

I have a Python 2 codebase which I'm migrating to Python 3. The old codebase uses

```
import string

foo = string.replace(s, old, new)
foo = string.strip(s)
foo = string.find(s, sub, start, end)
```

I moved it with 2to3, but this gives an error. My guess is that I have to replace the above by

```
foo = s.replace(old, new)
foo = s.strip()
foo = s.find(sub, start, end)
```

I looked at the documentation:

- [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) vs [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)
- [`string.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) vs [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)
- [`string.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) vs [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

They look exactly the same. Why were those functions in the `string` module in the first place? Was it a change before Python 2.7? Is there maybe a performance difference or some special cases which are treated differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the [CPython 2.7 `string` module source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/string.py#L323), they are trivial wrappers for the method calls. This likely was different in a much older Python. From the initial comments of the same code:

> Beginning with Python 1.6, many of these functions are implemented as
>   methods on the standard string object.